# How to deploy process in jbpm6 console from Eclipse?

Tags: deployment, jbpm

How to build and deploy process from Eclipse to jbpm6 console? When I right click on JBPM6 project or BPMN process definition, there is no option of deploying.

Is there an ant script to generate deployable process archive from an eclipse jbpm6 project?

When I ask about Guvnor, people say its removed from Jbpm 6. Where do my deployment go then?

Is there a documentation about the structure of deployment file? Can I deploy my own web services/rest services/EJBs along with JBPM process?

Camunda has a very well documented process deployment model. I am expecting similar model from JBPM6, but there is very little documentation.

http://www.bpm-guide.de/2011/09/28/less-code-bpm-with-camunda-fox-server-activiti-and-jboss-as-7/

Answer (score 0):

There was a huge change in technology in the project for the 6 release, so you need to wait until the final community version is out. Now guvnor was replaced by a different more up to date repository where now all your deployments go. The structure of a deployable artifact is a regular maven project, which make your life easier when you need to deal with dependencies between packages. 
Please check the following URL to see the changes in the infrastructure: 
http://blog.athico.com/2013/06/goodbye-guvnor-hello-drools-workbench.html

Comment: Can I hot deploy my java code changes using kie web project authoring->build and deploy feature?